# Datatables - sort column that contains age range/YADCF cumulative filter ( using columnDefs )

Tags: sorting, datatables, filtering, yadcf

I'm using Datatables to show groups, phases and age (ranges). Now, the column containing the age range is sorted as a string but I would like it to sort after age range. 
Therefore, ages 10-12 comes before 3-8 and 4-10 comes before 4-8.

On top of that I'm using YADCF to achive cumulative filtering, the idea is:

1. You see the complete overview.
2. You select your age (range)
3. The list of Phases should only contain items based on previous selection.
4. Only the groups matching the age range and selected phase will be shown.

**Question 1**

How do I achive the sorting function for the Age column? Have tried various things but makes no difference.

**Question 2**

When setting "cumulative_filtering" option to true, I'm getting a JS error "TypeError: t.split is not a function" which I guess has to do with data.Age.Min and data.Age.Max.

**HTML**

```
<label for="AgeFilter" class="sr-only">Age</label>
<div id="AgeFilter"></div>

<label for="PhaseFilter" class="sr-only">Phase</label>
<div id="PhaseFilter"></div>

<table id="Table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Phase</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
var DT = $('#Table').DataTable( {
    data: [{"Id":0,"Name":"Group 0","Phase":{"Id":1,"Name":"Phase 1"},"Age":{"Min":3,"Max":8}},{"Id":1,"Name":"Group 1","Phase":{"Id":1,"Name":"Phase 1"},"Age":{"Min":3,"Max":8}},{"Id":2,"Name":"Group 2","Phase":{"Id":1,"Name":"Phase 1"},"Age":{"Min":3,"Max":8}},{"Id":3,"Name":"Group 3","Phase":{"Id":1,"Name":"Phase 1"},"Age":{"Min":3,"Max":8}},{"Id":4,"Name":"Group 4","Phase":{"Id":1,"Name":"Phase 1"},"Age":{"Min":3,"Max":8}},{"Id":5,"Name":"Group 5","Phase":{"Id":1,"Name":"Phase 1"},"Age":{"Min":4,"Max":8}},{"Id":6,"Name":"Group 6","Phase":{"Id":1,"Name":"Phase 1"},"Age":{"Min":4,"Max":8}},{"Id":7,"Name":"Group 7","Phase":{"Id":1,"Name":"Phase 1"},"Age":{"Min":4,"Max":8}},{"Id":8,"Name":"Group 8","Phase":{"Id":1,"Name":"Phase 1"},"Age":{"Min":4,"Max":8}},{"Id":9,"Name":"Group 9","Phase":{"Id":1,"Name":"Phase 1"},"Age":{"Min":4,"Max":8}},{"Id":10,"Name":"Group 10","Phase":{"Id":1,"Name":"Phase 1"},"Age":{"Min":4,"Max":8}},{"Id":11,"Name":"Group 11","Phase":{"Id":2,"Name":"Phase 2"},"Age":{"Min":4,"Max":10}},{"Id":12,"Name":"Group 12","Phase":{"Id":2,"Name":"Phase 2"},"Age":{"Min":4,"Max":10}},{"Id":13,"Name":"Group 13","Phase":{"Id":2,"Name":"Phase 2"},"Age":{"Min":4,"Max":10}},{"Id":14,"Name":"Group 14","Phase":{"Id":2,"Name":"Phase 2"},"Age":{"Min":4,"Max":10}},{"Id":15,"Name":"Group 15","Phase":{"Id":2,"Name":"Phase 2"},"Age":{"Min":4,"Max":10}},{"Id":16,"Name":"Group 16","Phase":{"Id":2,"Name":"Phase 2"},"Age":{"Min":10,"Max":12}},{"Id":17,"Name":"Group 17","Phase":{"Id":2,"Name":"Phase 2"},"Age":{"Min":10,"Max":12}},{"Id":18,"Name":"Group 18","Phase":{"Id":2,"Name":"Phase 2"},"Age":{"Min":10,"Max":12}},{"Id":19,"Name":"Group 19","Phase":{"Id":2,"Name":"Phase 2"},"Age":{"Min":10,"Max":12}}],
    autoWidth: false,
    pageLength: -1,
    order: [[ 2, "asc" ], [ 3, "asc" ]],
    columnDefs: [
        { targets: 0, data: "Id" }, 
        { targets: 1, data: 'Name' },
        { targets: 2, data: function ( data, type, val, meta ) {
            if (type === 'display') {
                return data.Phase.Name;

            }else if (type === 'filter') {
                return data.Phase.Name;
            }
            // 'sort', 'type' and undefined all just use the integer
            return data.Phase.Id;
        } },
        { targets: 3, data: function ( data, type, val, meta ) {
            if (type === 'display') {
                if(data.Age.Min == data.Age.Max) return data.Age.Max;
                return data.Age.Min + '-' + data.Age.Max;

            }else if (type === 'filter') {
                return data.Age.Min + '-' + data.Age.Max;
            }
            // 'sort', 'type' and undefined all just use the integer
            return [data.Age.Min,data.Age.Max];
        } }
    ]
});
yadcf.init(DT, [
    {
        column_number : 2, 
        filter_container_id: 'PhaseFilter', 
        filter_default_label: 'Phase', 
        //filter_reset_button_text: false, 
        filter_match_mode: 'exact', 
        style_class: 'form-control'
    },
    {
        column_number : 3, 
        filter_container_id: 'AgeFilter', 
        filter_default_label: 'Age', 
        //filter_reset_button_text: false, 
        filter_match_mode: 'exact', 
        style_class: 'form-control',
        sort_as: 'num'
    }
], {
 //  cumulative_filtering: true
});
```

});

JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Webkungen/kmorw24f/2/

### Edit

Regarding the custom sorting function, I've tried:

```
sort_as_custom_func: function(one,two) {
    return (one < two);
},
```

Problem is it seems I cannot access the Age.Min and Age.Max, the one and two values are still a string i.e. 3-8 so don't understand how to compare the two values.

Answer (score 0):

As to Question 1, you should implement your own custom sorting function `sort_as_custom_func` (read docs)

As to Question  2 , you need to set your columns to `column_data_type: "rendered_html",` and to to implement `column_data_render` functions, read more in the [related issue](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/382)
(its not documented yet)

[I implemented it for you here](https://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/omr2v1ku/27/)

as follows

```
yadcf.init(DT, [
    {
        column_number : 2, 
        filter_container_id: 'PhaseFilter', 
        filter_default_label: 'Phase', 
        //filter_reset_button_text: false, 
        filter_match_mode: 'exact', 
        style_class: 'form-control',
        column_data_type: "rendered_html",
        column_data_render: function (data) {
            return data.Phase.Name;
        }
    },
    {
        column_number : 3, 
        filter_container_id: 'AgeFilter', 
        filter_default_label: 'Age', 
        //filter_reset_button_text: false, 
        filter_match_mode: 'exact', 
        style_class: 'form-control',
        sort_as: 'num',
        column_data_type: "rendered_html",
        column_data_render: function (data) {
            return data.Age.Min + '-' + data.Age.Max;
        }
    }
], {
   cumulative_filtering: true
});
```

});

Comment: Perfect, Q2 working fine now. However, can't access the age integers in my custom sort, have edited my original question.

Comment: using yadcf version 0.9.4 from cdnjs.cloudflare.com gives me `TypeError: d[l]._aFilterData is undefined` while the 0.9.4.beta.10 you're using works fine with my code.

Comment: @Webkungen , you better always use the latest beta (it contains bugs fix / new features)

Comment: @Webkungen , please provide a relevant jsfiddle with the sort issue, and next time please post your questions one by one

Comment: here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Webkungen/41q5wkju/3/ unfortunately I don't understand the docs in this matter. If I output "a" and "b" from my fiddle I get "a = 10-12", "b = 3-8" so don't get how I should compare the two. Thanks

Comment: one solution is to make an object / map in which the keys will be strings "10-12", "3-8", etc... and each key will hold a value (order value) by which you will do the sort logic